# Update all UITableView cell's detailLabel

Tags: ios

The detail label on each cell of my UITableViewCotroller gives the size of the folder it represents.  The size may change, and whenever it does I need to change all of the detailLabels. One way would be to perform a reload, [tableview reloadData];, however the many images make it slow. Is there a way to just update the label?

I tried the method but I don't seem to be able to get it to work:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
…
[tableView endUpdates]; 

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where does `indexPath` in `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` come from?

Comment: You could keep a reference to the images, and provide the cached copy when reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to fast enumerate through `[self.tableview visibleCells]`, and change the labels on those. This is assuming the data that the tableview is getting in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be up to date. That way, all the visible cells will be updated immediately, and the rest will be updated as soon as they get visible.

Was that understandable? Let me know if it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try below methods,

```
- (void)loadDetailsForOnscreenRows
{
    if ([self.entries count] > 0)
    {
        NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

        for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Your text";

        }
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
    {
            [self loadDetailsForOnscreenRows];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self loadDetailsForOnscreenRows];
}
```

Also, Refer apple's [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) for more details to load table lazily.